# How do I climb onto the top of the train?

Tags: battlefield-3

On the first mission, just after the bad guy plants explosives on the door and decouples the other half of the train, you are left hanging on to rungs at the side of the train by just your fingertips.

At this point the game appears to prompt you to hit the spacebar, which I do, but each time the prompt turns red, indicating that I have failed in some way, and I fall back down to the bottom rung of the ladder. After about three tries you fall off and die.

Is there a knack to the timing of pressing the spacebar (the prompt appears to pulsate) or is there something really obvious I am missing?

Comment: I am having the same problem when trying to climb the train. No matter how fast i press the space bar it just won't climb. I am on the verge of uninstalling it.

Comment: This was almost a showstopper for me, too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're supposed to tap the spacebar as fast as you can. This is indicated by the input prompt flashing rapidly.

If it turns red, you simply didn't tap fast enough, and the action fails. Fail enough times and you're dead.

Comment: The most ridiculous way of communicating this to the player. The most ridiculous way of actually doing something in the game in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There is a glitch in the software, same as on the PS3 that no matter how fast you press it, it won't climb the car. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling and then it worked.